# OPENOCD script Error: wrong # args: should be "expr expression"

Tags: linux, openocd

I am trying to run OpenOCD with the scripts provided at:
https://gitlab.cs.hs-rm.de/CaroloCup/openocd-am57xx-scripts

Particularly, just the simple main script `am57_mpu_0.cfg`.

The command is:

```
openocd -f interface/jlink.cfg -f ./jlink_config.cfg -f ./am57_mpu_0.cfg
```

which fails with:

```
./am57_mpu_0.cfg:110: Error: wrong # args: should be "expr expression"
```

while line 110 looks pretty normal to me:

```
set _dbgbase [expr 0x80000000 | ($_coreid << 13)]
```

I tried to simplify it for the test purpose as:

```
set _dbgbase [expr (40+1)]
```

but still have the same error.

I will be thankful for any hint what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There was the syntax change in TCL which requires the expression to be enclosed into {}.
The syntax change took place in July 2022. But Fedora repository installs version 0.11 as the last, which was packed in 2021.
So, the question is why Fedora updates do not contain the last update to version 0.12 where all scripts are already updated to have these {}.